# regex to match sections in file and grouping

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a text file of the following format:

```
*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0
*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2
1,2,3
4,5,6
*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8
4,5,6
3,4,6
*CMD3,U4=0
par,1,2
par,3,4
```

I want to make a key value pair. The keys being the lines that start with an *, and the values is the lists below (everything, regardless of type etc...).

I was using regex in order to accomplish this.

I believe the expression to capture the lines that start with * is:

```
r'^ *\*.*'
```

Here is my code:

```
import re, mmap, os

with open(fn,'r') as fin:
    size = os.stat(fn).st_size
    data = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for m in re.finditer(r'^( *\*.*)(...)',data,re.M)
        print 1
        print m.group(1)
        print 2
        print m.group(2)
```

What should go in the (...) placeholder for the output to be:

```
1
*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0
2

1
*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2
2
1,2,3
4,5,6

1
*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8
2
4,5,6
3,4,6

1
*CMD3,U4=0
2
par,1,2
par,3,4
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted, `str.startwith('*')` is more than adequate to detect if a line starts with a '*'. Being a fan of Raymond Hettinger's work in `itertools` and `groupby`, I offer this approach to iterating over the several groups:

```
from itertools import groupby

def generate_groups(text):

    key_fn = lambda s: s.startswith('*')

    last = None
    for leading_star, following in groupby(text.splitlines(), key=key_fn):
        if not leading_star:
            # multiple rows not starting with '*', these are subs of last '*' row
            yield (last, list(following))
            last = None
        else:
            # multiple rows starting with '*'
            for f in following:
                if last is not None:
                    yield (last, [])
                last = f

    if last is not None:
        yield (last, [])

print(sample)
for group in (generate_groups(sample)):
    print(group)
```

prints

```
*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0
*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2
1,2,3
4,5,6
*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8
4,5,6
3,4,6
*CMD3,U4=0
par,1,2
par,3,4

('*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0', [])
('*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2', ['1,2,3', '4,5,6'])
('*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8', ['4,5,6', '3,4,6'])
('*CMD3,U4=0', ['par,1,2', 'par,3,4'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex that works:`(\*[\w,=]*)([\s\w,]*)`

**Explanation:**
This regex has two groups: first one `(\*[\w,=]*)` is for key and only matches any line starting with "*", while the second one `([\s\w,]*)` matches all lines not starting with "*". Please note you will have to strip the values to remove unwanted whitespaces.

**Output:**

```
Match 1
1. *CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0 
2.  

Match 2
1. *CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2 
2.  1,2,3 4,5,6  

Match 3
1. *CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8 
2.  4,5,6 3,4,6  

Match 4
1. *CMD3,U4=0 
2.  par,1,2 par,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a key value pair.

I don't think regex is the best way of accomplishing your goal.  Iterate through the lines, set keys in your collection to lines that start with `'*'`, and append to the value the lines that don't start with `'*'`.

```
current_key = None
data_map = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('*'):
        current_key = line
        data_map[current_key] = []
    else:
        if current_key is None:
            continue #no known key above, skip
        data_map[current_key].append(line)
```

And then to get your printed output:

```
>>>for k, v in data_map.items():
        print(1)
        print(k)
        print(2)
        print(*v, '\n', sep = '\n')


1
*CMD3,U4=0
2
par,1,2
par,3,4


1
*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8
2
4,5,6
3,4,6


1
*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0
2


1
*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2
2
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive my being so blunt but there is no need for regex. You can do this more simply. Check for the appearance of a '*' character at the beginning of a line and act accordingly.

```
>>> begun = False
>>> with open('temp.txt') as text:
...     for line in text.readlines():
...         if not line:
...             break
...         line = line.strip()
...         if line.startswith('*'):
...             if begun:
...                 print ()
...             else:
...                 begun = True
...             print (1)
...             print (line)
...             print (2)
...         else:
...             print (line)
...             
1
*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0
2

1
*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2
2
1,2,3
4,5,6

1
*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8
2
4,5,6
3,4,6

1
*CMD3,U4=0
2
par,1,2
par,3,4
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried `for m in re.finditer(r'^( *\*.*)([^*]+)',data,re.M):` and it seems to give valid results, trim any white space using `strip()` and the exact output can be found,

1

*CMD1,I1=0,I2=0,I3=0

2

1
*CMD2,I1=0,I2=1,I3=2

2

1,2,3

4,5,6

1

*CMD3,U1=0,U2=9,U3=8

2

4,5,6

3,4,6

1

*CMD3,U4=0

2

par,1,2

par,3,4

Comment: @thanks for the tip billy, have made the suggested changes, to the best of my knowledge, if there is a diff/better way kindly do share

Comment: I am not sure, if it is right to ask or not, since the answer has been marked not useful despite getting the correct result,
I am wondering if my solution is wrong,